# Linear Codes : Error detection

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, coding-theory, standard-error

The code words of a linear code $C$ have the length $n=5$.

Writing the code words into a matrix to get the linear independent ones, we get the following: 
\begin{equation*}\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow \ldots \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\end{equation*}

So the dimension of $C$ is $m=2$.

Wir have also the minimum distance $d(C) =3$.

The generator matrix of $C$ is \begin{equation*}G=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\end{equation*}

The canonical generator matrix is \begin{equation*}G'=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\end{equation*}

And the canonical parity check matrix is 
\begin{equation*}H'=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\end{equation*}

Now there is the following question:

How many errors are at least detected at the code $C$ if $11100$ is received?

Could you give me a hint for that?

Answer (score 0):

It's easy enough by hand in this case: we only have 4 code words (dimension 2 over binary and $2^2=4$) all of which are enumerated in your first matrix as its rows.
We have received $r=11100$. Compute the distances to the code words:

$$d(00000,r)=3, d(01101,r)=2, d(10111,r)=3, d(11010,r)=2$$, so we detect (at least) $2$ errors. ($2$ being the most likely tpyically). We cannot correct $r$ because there are two code words at distance $2$. Minimum distance $3$ tells us we can correct 1 error and detect at most 2.

Comment: That means that the number of errors that are detected is equal to the distance of two codes,right? I haven't really understood the last part of your answer: "**We cannot correct r because there are two code words at distance 2. Minimum distance 3 tells us we can correct 1 error and detect at most 2.**" Coyld you explain that further to me?

Comment: @MaryStar if one error is made we can find a unique  codeword at distance 1 (if more, these codewords would be at most 2 apart). Making 2 errors either leaves us distance 1 from another codeword or distance 2 from one. So we can always detect 2 errors, but sometimes we get a wrong decoding. So with minimal distance $d$ we can sometimes detect $d-1$ errors, depending on how the codewords are spread out.

Comment: Since the code C has minimum distance 3 it holds that at most 2 errors can be detected and that 1 error can be corrected. So, since at the code $C_3$ there are at least $2$ errors we cannot correct them all. Is that what you mean? Or have I understood that wrong?

Comment: @MaryStar no that’s right. We received a word distance at least $2$ from any codeword so we know at least 2 errors have been made and we cannot correct it as we have 2 codewords at exactly distance 2.

Comment: Ahh ok!! If we had more code words in the code is there also an other way to calculate the minimum number of errors? Maybe with the parity-check matrix?

Comment: @MaryStar it’s also the minimal norm of a nonzero codeword. So you don’t have to check all pairs.

Comment: What do you mean? Could you explain that further to  me?

Comment: @MaryStar the minimal distance of a linear code equals the minimal weight of a nonzero codeword. You should know that already.